# How to get date from innerHTML / textContent javascript

Tags: javascript, date, innerhtml

Here is the JavaScript code that I am trying to use to get a date from inside a  element populated with several

elements.  The 9th element contains a date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.  When I use this code, it doesn't seem to be converting the elements into a JavaScript date -- instead I get [native code] when I try to dump the date variable.  Any ideas?

**Partial code:**

```
if (optvalue == 2) { 
    for (i = 0; i < trans_array.length; i++) {
        var cn = trans_array[i].childNodes;
        var dts = cn[9];

        try {
            var transdt = new Date(dts.innerHTML);
            if (transdt < prior_month) {
                trans_array[i].classList.add("hide");
                alert("node hiddent!");
            }
            alert(transdt.getDay + " / " + transdt.getMonth + " / " + transdt.getFullYear);
        } catch(err) {
            alert("Error: Inner HTML is not a date:" + dts.innerHTML)       
        }    
    }    
alert("Value is 2");
}

<div class="transaction_item prior_day" id="trans-88">
<!----------- Sub Row 1 ------------------->
<p class="tiday">Tue</p>
<p class="tipayee">Coutry Boy Gas</p>
<p class="ticredit">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="tidebit">7.02</p>
<p class="tibalance">1.24</p>
<p class="solid_box" id="check-88" onclick="toggle_checkmark(88)">&nbsp;</p>
<p onclick="edit(1, 88)">Edit</p>
<!-------------- Sub Row 2 --------------------->
<p class="tidate">2018-04-17</p>
<p class="ticat">Miscellaneous Expense</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p class="timemo">Gas for Car </p>
</div>
```

Comment: What does ``console.log(dts.innerHTML)`` return?

Comment: What does `console.log(dts.innerHTML)` show ?

Comment: @Kokogino lol nice one. Almost telepathic huh ? :D

Comment: @Isac Yeah, almost. xD

Comment: share console.log(dts)

Comment: made a fiddle fixing it for you,  look at https://jsfiddle.net/kh9pandv/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correct, you want to get a string date and convert to a `date()`, right? If yes, why not get the value directly from the element with class `.tidate` then create a `new date()`?

This will return a complete date with day, month, year and time, to get just what you need, you can use the get methods from the `date()`, like:
`getDate()`: Returns the day of the month (1-31)
`getFullYear()`: Returns the year (4-digit years)
`getMonth()`: Returns the month (0-11)

Basic Example:

```js
var date_string = document.querySelector('.tidate').textContent;
var nDate = new Date(date_string);
console.log("Complete Date: " + nDate);
console.log("Day:" + nDate.getDate());
console.log("Month:" + nDate.getMonth()); //ADD +1 to get "real life" month 
console.log("Year:" + nDate.getFullYear());
```

```html
<!----------- Sub Row 1 ------------------->
<p class="tiday">Tue</p>
<p class="tipayee">Coutry Boy Gas</p>
<p class="ticredit">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="tidebit">7.02</p>
<p class="tibalance">1.24</p>
<p class="solid_box" id="check-88" onclick="toggle_checkmark(88)">&nbsp;</p>
<p onclick="edit(1, 88)">Edit</p>
<!-------------- Sub Row 2 --------------------->
<p class="tidate">2018-04-17</p>
```

If I understood wrong, please, clarify to me what exactly is your need or post a code that we can reproduce the issue in a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding I have made code modification and created a fiddle.

Here is the working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kh9pandv/

Modifications:

```
 var dts = cn[9];
```

to

```
 var dts = trans_array.querySelector('.tidate');
```

In alert, you were not calling functions, you just named the function.

```
alert(transdt.getDay() + " / " + transdt.getMonth() + " / " + transdt.getFullYear());
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is that you're accessing the property "getDay" instead of calling the function "getDay()"

Try changing your line

```
alert(transdt.getDay + " / " + transdt.getMonth + " / " + transdt.getFullYear);
```

to

```
alert(transdt.getDay() + " / " + transdt.getMonth() + " / " + transdt.getFullYear());
```